# Does anyone know why XAMPP has a host name ec2amaz-1qpqh3j with full privileges and no password protect?

Tags: phpmyadmin, xampp, hostname

I recently downloaded XAMPP to my local PC.
In phpAdmin, User accounts, there is a host name "ec2amaz-1qpqh3j".
I can easily remove the host from my phpMyAdmin.  That is not my concern.
I just want to pull attention to the latest XAMPP version (downloaded from original website apachefriends.org) coming with a questionable host inside the package.

Does anyone have an explanation?

Thank you.

Comment: @Dharman yes. I posted in the ApacheFriends Community.  I don't know of any other way to contact them.  However, since I didn't find anything other than a German Tweet on this subject, this is also to be a warning if there is something fishy going, unless it is cleared.

Comment: Either way, I took away all Privileges and put a password to the host name and root.  The problem thereafter was that I could not get back into phpMyAdmin until I manually entered my root password into >XAMPP >phpMyAdmin >config.inc.php .  Where it states $cfg['Servers'][$i]['AllowNoPassword'] = true;   change to false and enter your Password into where it says Password and default is empty.  Just FYI for those who run into same.

Comment: Interesting that there is not more documentation on this. It is in my xampp local DB Privileges also.

Comment: @Nexus7_2012 I would make it dormant and definitely password protect regardless.

Answer (score 1):

The above topic should be resolved.  I am posting the answer I received over at the ApacheFriends.org Forums:

```
Hi,

Thanks for reporting this issue. "ec2amaz-1qpqh3j" is the hostname of the machine we used the last time we generated the default MariaDB data using mysql_install_db.exe. When you use this binary to generate the MariaDB data folder, it creates a 'root'@'hostname' entry.

As a workaround, you can manually remove that entry from phpMyAdmin. We will release a new revision of the installers fixing this issue.

Regards,
Gonzalo
```

https://community.apachefriends.org/f/viewtopic.php?f=16&t=78574&p=266199#p266199